# Facebook Update Status not working: FB pulling wrong data from page

Tags: facebook

When I paste url in Update Status on Facebook, it does not pull the right data from the meta open graphics.  I've used FB's Object Debugger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) and all appears to be working fine except when they show the preview: it shows a messy title.
Any idea what the problem is?

-Richard

Comment: The url is http://www.nic.bc.ca/about_us/events_notices.aspx?e=2049#event2049

Comment: This behaviour is due to the fragment `#event2049`. The Facebook crawler takes the text from the element with `id="event2040"` and adds it to the title. To avoid this you can add the `id` to an empty element.

Comment: Your solution isn't possible - I'd need the accordion feature to work properly with the id or am I missing something?